# Recommendation for a Java in memory database

Tags: java, sql, database, in-memory-database, nosql

Looking for a recommendation.  I have a command line utility that now needs to process a large amount of data coming from a web service in a form of a CSV.

I need to run multiple tests on the data to look for anomalies and patterns.  I'd like the utility to be something that someone can download and not have to install or configure.

Is there a recommendation for a NoSQL or SQL database that I can just spin up in memory, load the CSV into a table and then run my queries against that data?

Can Redis be used without installation?  Something else?

Comment: what exactly do you need out of it? just a blob kvstore by primary key? json processing? query language?

Comment: How large does the data is going to be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple and reliable in memory database for fast java integration tests with support for JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444265/simple-and-reliable-in-memory-database-for-fast-java-integration-tests-with-supp)

Answer (score 7):

How about H2 Database? It's pure Java, in-memory and can be embedded into your application, see [Connecting to an Embedded (Local) Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html?highlight=embedded&search=embedded#embedded_databases)

example:

```
import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;

JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource();
ds.setURL("jdbc:h2:˜/test.db");
ds.setUser("sa");
ds.setPassword("sa");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

(adapted from http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbcx/JdbcDataSource.html)

If you want an in-memory database, change URL to something like *jdbc:h2:mem:test.db* or similar. Look for "in-memory Databases" in documentation.

Comment: @julianwki: nice, so this is a SQL database, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just look at their website, it starts with "Welcome to H2, the Java SQL database. The main features of H2 are.... ;-)

Comment: thanks!  I am a little hesitant to have something that leaves a file around, but it's a solid lead.

Comment: That's why you can use it complete in memory as I mentioned above.

Comment: @julianwki old thread, but H2 doesn't support a lot of SQL syntax, so pretty much useless.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Not only old thread, but closed question. Anyhow: Hardly depends on the use-case if that sql support is (or better: was) sufficient enough. And since 8 years have past, I hope the OP has solved his challenge already...

Answer (score 2):

I have not yet used it, but have a look at [JasDB](http://www.oberasoftware.com/jasdb/)

From the website.

> Quick Install guide
>
> JasDB is incredibly easy to get started with it is up and running
>   under a minute simply download and run it, or simply include it in
>   your project Instructions
>
> - Install JasDB by unzipping the download
> - Start the database using start.bat or start.sh
> - Open http://localhost:7050

From https://github.com/oberasoftware/jasdb/wiki/Using-In-memory-indexes-and-storage

> JasDB can run with full in memory based indexes and record storage.
>   The following configuration needs to be used in that case:
>
> ```
> <Storage>
>     <RecordWriter provider="inmemory"/>
>     <!--<RecordWriter provider="transactional"/>-->
> </Storage>
> ```