# Is it possible to rollback the database after each JUnit test case without using Spring framework?

Tags: java, junit, transactions, rollback

I'm trying to test the service which updates multiple tables from the database and I want to rollback the database to previous state after each test case. All solutions I have found are using @Transactional and @Rollback from Spring framework, but since my application is not a Spring web application, I would like to use javax @Transactional, which does not work for me.

Is this possible with javax at all or anything else except the Spring?

Comment: You could create programmatically a transaction in the ```@Before``` and rollback it in the ```@After```

Comment: @D.Lawrence do you have an example how to do this?

Comment: Are you using simple jdbc for your purpose?

Comment: @D.Lawrence yes

Answer (score 1):

Rollback a transaction isn't a good idea for test (integration test) as the constraint may not be validated before the commit.

You should:

1. have a DB only for integration tests (or an embedded db or a container db or in RAM db)
2. execute, for example in a [class rule](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/ClassRule.html) or in a [test rule](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html), script SQL in order to bring the db in a known status
3. execute a test
4. if test modifies the db then run a truncate of tables modified (again or in your class or test rule) and, before peform a new test, run again the script at point 2
5. run integration tests not so often as unit tests

Answer (score 0):

Better idea is to use in-memory database:
H2 https://www.h2database.com/
[Recommendation for a Java in memory database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984542/recommendation-for-a-java-in-memory-database)

Not always and not everything in database can be rolled-back to initial state ( ex. sequences ).